# Create a Database specific Login from C# which cannot edit,update or delete any other database except the one mapped to it or set as default

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, authentication

I have created a login with the name "bilal" and "password" as password and mapped it to the database "MyDatabase". But when I try to insert record in another database using this login it doesn't deny inserting. I want this user to only a database specific user which is "MyDatabase".
Here are the strings I have declared. Here is my code.

```
string loginName = "bilal";
 string password = "password";
 string serverName = "BILAL\\BILAL";
 string databaseName = "MyDatabase";

protected void CreateUser()
        {
            Server svr = new Server(serverName);
            var db = svr.Databases[databaseName];
            var IsUser = svr.Logins[loginName];
            if (db != null && IsUser == null)
            {

                Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Login login = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Login(svr, loginName);
                login.DefaultDatabase = "master";
                login.GetDatabaseUser(databaseName);
                DatabaseMapping dbMapping = new DatabaseMapping(loginName,databaseName,loginName);
                login.DefaultDatabase = databaseName;
                login.LoginType = LoginType.SqlLogin;
                login.Create(password, LoginCreateOptions.None);
                login.Enable();

                User user = new User(db, loginName);
                user.UserType = UserType.SqlLogin;
                user.Login = loginName;
                user.Create();
                // add a role
                user.AddToRole("db_owner");
            }
            CrateAndFillTable();
        }
```

Here is my 2nd method which is trying to create a table and insert data into it in another database using the login i have created in above method.

```
  protected void CrateAndFillTable()
        {
            databaseName = "TestDB";
            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                conn.Close();
            ConnectionString = "Integrated Security=true;" +
            "Initial Catalog=" + databaseName + ";" +
            "Data Source=" + serverName + ";" +
            "User Id=" + loginName + ";"+
            "Password=" + password + ";";
            conn.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
            conn.Open();
            sql = "CREATE TABLE myTable" +
            "(myId INTEGER CONSTRAINT PKeyMyId PRIMARY KEY," +
            "myName CHAR(50), myAddress CHAR(255), myBalance FLOAT)";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                // Adding records into the table
                sql = "INSERT INTO myTable(myId, myName, myAddress, myBalance) " +
                "VALUES (1001, 'M Bilal', 'Street1, Lahore', 23.98 ) ";
                cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (SqlException ae)
            {
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove "Integrated Security=true;" from your ConnectionString in CrateAndFillTable and try again. Integrated Security uses your Windows Id instead of Sqllogin credentials.

Comment: Thank you, It works for me. As I am new to stackoverflow, so please rate my question. Thank you once again.